# Show/hide multiple different content in divs from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I have 5 different images that should work as buttons, each of these buttons should trigger the content in a div. I would like to have a default content in the div when the page loads but is replaced by whatever button is pressed, the content from the pressed button should be replaced when i click another button.

This is what i've got now.

HTML:

```js
 $('.section-link').click(function() {
        var cur = $('.section-link').index($(this));
        $('.section-display').removeClass('active');
        $('.section-display').eq(cur).addClass('active');
      });
```

```css
.section-display:not(.active) {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><img class="button1 section-link" src="button1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="button2 section-link" src="button2.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="button3 section-link" src="button3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="button4 section-link" src="button4.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="button5 section-link" src="button5.jpg" alt=""></a>

    // Default CONTENT when page loaded
    <div class="section-display active">
      <h2 class="title">Default Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-display">
      <h2 class="title">First Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-display">
      <h2 class="title">Second Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-display">
      <h2 class="title">Third Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-display">
      <h2 class="title">Fourth Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section-display">
      <h2 class="title">Fifth Ipsum</h2>
      <h2 class="text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: works fine for me .. https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9tm92sfc/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Yeah it's "working" but i would like some help to get my default content visible on page load and the other 5 buttons to trigger the divs with different content. Atm the default content is like the others.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Check here https://jsfiddle.net/9tm92sfc/1/ When i click any of the buttons now the old default content should be overwritten, thats what i would like to have. Thanks !

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9tm92sfc/2/ .. simply use `$('.section-link').index($(this)) + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  I didn't notice the JQuery tag on the question at first. Here's an updated answer that uses that.

Don't use hyperlinks when you aren't navigating anywhere. It's semantically incorrect and unnecessarily messes with the browser history. You can, instead place your images inside of the `button` element or just add `click` event handlers to the images themselves, which is what I'm showing below.

Also, if you store the content in an array of objects, you can eliminate having to create 5 separate div structures and be able to just update a single one:

```js
// Put all the images in a JavaScript array
var $imgs = $(".section-link");

// If you store your content in an array of objects, you can do this without creating 
// more than one display div. You'll just get the content from the object in the
// array that has the same index as the image (within a different array)
var data = [
  {
    title: "Default Ipsum 1",
    text: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },
  {
    title: "Default Ipsum 2",
    text: "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },
  {
    title: "Default Ipsum 3",
    text: "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },
  {
    title: "Default Ipsum 4",
    text: "4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },
  {
    title: "Default Ipsum 5",
    text: "5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  },  
];

// Get reference to the output area
var $outputDiv = $(".section-display");

// Set a click event handler for each of the images
$imgs.on("click", function(){
  // Find the child elements within the output div that need updating and
  // extract the content from the array of objects that correspond
  // to the index of the image that was clicked.
  $(".title", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].title);
  $(".text", $outputDiv).text(data[$(this).index()-1].text);    
});
```

```css
/* This is only here to make the images visible since they don't 
   actually have valid src paths right now. */
img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- See how much simpler the HTML is now? -->
<img class="section-link" src="button1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="section-link" src="button2.jpg" alt="">
<img class="section-link" src="button3.jpg" alt="">
<img class="section-link" src="button4.jpg" alt="">
<img class="section-link" src="button5.jpg" alt="">

<div class="section-display active">
  <h2 class="title">Default Title</h2>
  <h2 class="text">Default Content</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, alot cleaner! Just one thing before solved. As i commented on Mohameds suggestion above how would i add so that my default content is not connected to any button and the other 5 buttons replaces the content.

Comment: @Petersson It's just a matter of placing the default content statically in the HTML and removing the JavaScript that sets the default content. I've updated the answer to do that.

Comment: Thanks, how should i put the images correctly in the " var $imgs = $(".section-link"); "

Comment: @Scorr-Marcus Im getting this error when trying to press any of the button images "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: @Petersson First, you don't have to do anything with the images except set correct values for `src` in the HTML. In other words, the JavaScript doesn't need to change at all. As for the error, it's important that the order of the JavaScript is as I've written it here. the `data` array must be declared before the code that reads from it.

Comment: @Petersson Also, remember that my answer has the HTML set up differently than your original code, so you need to adjust that too.

Comment: Okay i got it working, its VERY sensitive of placement.. My problem tho is that i have other jqury scripts running and they break if i move the script link from my head tag.. And this breaks if i place the jquery link in the head tag.. Any ideas of a solution here?

Comment: Ok i fixed it by adding  $(document).ready(function(){ and then placing the jquery link in the header so it all works perfect now. Thanks a lot!